# Boiler efficiency

Tags: thermodynamics

Is there any relation between boiler efficiency and exit temperature of flue gas? Or relation between fuel saving and exit temperature of flue gas in thermal power plants?

Comment: Of course. The hotter the flue gas, the less of its thermal energy is available for the heating of the boiler. Ideally the exit temperature of the flue gas should be the entry temperature of the boiler. We usually try to avoid in real life that for technical reasons.